# Mysql. В пароле есть &

Tags: mysql

В пароле к базе есть `&`. При выполнении `mysqldump`, выдает следующее :

> sh: 1: nY_5: not found

Перед n в пароле стоит &, тоесть ???

```
&nY_5.
```

Как обойти проблему, чтобы команда воспринимала весь пароль ?

Comment: \\& так может ?

Comment: `&amp;` скорее всего

Comment: @PauloBerezini спасибо прокатило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте экранировать `\\&`

В вашем случае должно получиться так:

```
\\&nY_5
```